# Why does the kernel schedule to modprobe threads print this the log of a thread that is not a kernel thread?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

The system always prints the following log when running normally.I don't think the program should go to kthread_is_per_cpu if modprobe thread is not a kernel thread.Normal scheduling other applications do not print the following log.Therefore, want to know what is wrong with the system.

kernle version : 5.10

```
[  606.544474] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  606.544536] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 11 at kernel/kthread.c:83 kthread_is_per_cpu+0x30/0x38
[  606.545889] Modules linked in:
[  606.548932] CPU: 2 PID: 11 Comm: rcu_sched Not tainted 5.10.59-SUNPLUS-v8-g34739fa8e513 #3
[  606.557173] Hardware name: Sunplus Q645 (DT)
[  606.561429] pstate: 80c00085 (Nzcv daIf +PAN +UAO -TCO BTYPE=--)
[  606.567417] pc : kthread_is_per_cpu+0x30/0x38
[  606.571759] lr : can_migrate_task+0x114/0x230
[  606.576096] sp : ffffffc01159ba00
[  606.579394] x29: ffffffc01159ba00 x28: ffffff81e0cd6ee8
[  606.584689] x27: ffffff81e0cd6e00 x26: ffffffc010fe6840
[  606.589983] x25: ffffffc0111e8f60 x24: 0000000000000080
[  606.595279] x23: ffffff81ff966840 x22: ffffff81ff967290
[  606.600573] x21: ffffff81e0cd6e00 x20: ffffff81ff967240
[  606.605868] x19: ffffffc01159baf0 x18: 0000000000000002
[  606.611163] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000
[  606.616457] x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 0000000000000000
[  606.621752] x13: 0000000000000001 x12: 0000000000000000
[  606.627048] x11: 0000000000000002 x10: 000000000001d400
[  606.632342] x9 : 0000000000000373 x8 : 0000000000000000
[  606.637637] x7 : 000000000001d400 x6 : 000000100525bff7
[  606.642931] x5 : 00ffffffffffffff x4 : 0000000000000001
[  606.648226] x3 : 0000000000000400 x2 : 0000000000000002
[  606.653521] x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : ffffff81e0cd6e00
[  606.658816] Call trace:
[  606.661249]  kthread_is_per_cpu+0x30/0x38
[  606.665242]  load_balance+0x350/0xd18
[  606.668886]  newidle_balance+0x188/0x450   fair.c
[  606.672792]  pick_next_task_fair+0x50/0x388
[  606.676962]  __schedule+0x104/0x6f8
[  606.680430]  schedule+0x48/0xd0
[  606.683556]  schedule_timeout+0x19c/0x328
[  606.687551]  rcu_gp_kthread+0x480/0x1020
[  606.691454]  kthread+0xfc/0x128
[  606.694581]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x34
[  606.698137] ---[ end trace 3fba7c6a9600b2aa ]---
```

At the bottom is T32 trace information.The flags member in the data structure indicates whether the thread is a kernel thread
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is kernel bug,update the kernel version to 5.12.4 or higher version solve the problem.